flutter Navigator push method dispose MaterialApp?
i want to Navigate MyApp -> Home -> SearchStore
but it doesnt work.
this is my MyApp , Home , SearchStore Widget code
MyApp Widget
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: AppStyle().appTheme,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: checkUserInfo(context),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(
                child: SvgPicture.asset(
                  'assets/brand/big_logo.svg',
                ),
              );
            } else if (snapshot.data!) {
              return const Home();
            } else {
              return const SignIn();
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Home Widget
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home ({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text(
          'search store',
          style: AppStyle().appTheme.textTheme.displayLarge,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        Hero(
          tag: 'hero',
          child: TextField(
            readOnly: true,
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => SearchStore(),
                ),
              );
            },
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
              prefixIconColor: AppStyle().brandColor,
              hintText: 'need store name',
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: AppStyle().brandColor,
                  width: 1.5,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              ),
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: AppStyle().brandColor,
                  width: 1.5,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}


SearchStore Widget
class SearchStore extends StatelessWidget {
  const SearchStore({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Hero(
            tag: 'hero',
            child: TextField(
              readOnly: false,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                prefixIconColor: AppStyle().brandColor,
                hintText: 'need store name',
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: AppStyle().brandColor,
                    width: 1.5,
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: AppStyle().brandColor,
                    width: 1.5,
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


i want Navigator push home -> SearchStore widget but when use Navigator.push method, error comes out
this is error call stack
debugCheckHasMaterial.<anonymous closure> (c:\Users\jun\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\material\debug.dart:38)
debugCheckHasMaterial (c:\Users\jun\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\material\debug.dart:63)
_TextFieldState.build (c:\Users\jun\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\material\text_field.dart:1324)
StatefulElement.build (c:\Users\jun\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\widgets\framework.dart:5592)
ComponentElement.performRebuild (c:\Users\jun\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\widgets\framework.dart:5480)
StatefulElement.performRebuild (c:\Users\jun\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\widgets\framework.dart:5643)
Element.rebuild (c:\Users\jun\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\widgets\framework.dart:5196)
ComponentElement._firstBuild (c:\Users\jun\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\widgets\framework.dart:5462)
StatefulElement._firstBuild (c:\Users\jun\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\widgets\framework.dart:5634)
ComponentElement.mount (c:\Users\jun\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\widgets\framework.dart:5456)
Element.inflateWidget (c:\Users\jun\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\widgets\framework.dart:4335)
Element.updateChild (c:\Users\jun\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\widgets\framework.dart:3846)
ComponentElement.performRebuild (c:\Users\jun\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\widgets\framework.dart:5505)
Element.rebuild (c:\Users\jun\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\widgets\framework.dart:5196)
ComponentElement._firstBuild (c:\Users\jun\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\widgets\framework.dart:5462)
ComponentElement.mount (c:\Users\jun\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\widgets\framework.dart:5456)
Element.inflateWidget (c:\Users\jun\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\widgets\framework.dart:4335)
Element.updateChild (c:\Users\jun\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\widgets\framework.dart:3846)
ComponentElement.performRebuild (c:\Users\jun\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\widgets\framework.dart:5505)
StatefulElement.performRebuild (c:\Users\jun\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\widgets\framework.dart:5643


and this is Debug Console
No Material widget found.
TextField widgets require a Material widget ancestor within the closest LookupBoundary.
In Material Design, most widgets are conceptually "printed" on a sheet of material. In Flutter's material library, that material is represented by the Material widget. It is the Material widget that renders ink splashes, for instance. Because of this, many material library widgets require that there be a Material widget in the tree above them.
To introduce a Material widget, you can either directly include one, or use a widget that contains Material itself, such as a Card, Dialog, Drawer, or Scaffold.
The specific widget that could not find a Material ancestor was: TextField

and this is WidgetTree
enter image description here
what should i do?
i think
textField need MaterialApp but Navigator push method -> new UiStack on MateriApp -> No MaterialApp

Wrap MaterialAPP and Scaffold

 Hero(
                        tag: 'hero',
                        child: TextField(
                          readOnly: true,
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).push(
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => MaterialApp(
                                  home: Scaffold(
                                    body: SearchStore(),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                            prefixIconColor: AppStyle().brandColor,
                            hintText: 'need store name.',
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: AppStyle().brandColor,
                                width: 1.5,
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: AppStyle().brandColor,
                                width: 1.5,
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )

but same error call stack , debug console
i dont know what should i do

I suggest that every Screen should has its own Scaffold().
So push the future builder above the scaffold in the MaterialApp widget like this:
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: AppStyle().appTheme,
      home: FutureBuilder(
          future: checkUserInfo(context),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return LoadingScreen();
              
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return const Home();
            } else {
              return const SignIn();
            }
          },
        ),
    );
  }
}

and every screen is surrounded by a scaffold:
example: Home
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home ({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            'search store',
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Hero(
            tag: 'hero',
            child: TextField(
              readOnly: true,
              onTap: () {

                print('Pressed..........');
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                fillColor: Colors.orange,
                filled: true,
                hintText: 'need store name',
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    width: 1.5,
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    width: 1.5,
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

do the same for SignIn and Loading screens.
Hope it helps you.
